# Is it possible to detach and re-attach to a spawned process using separate expect processes?

Tags: process, expect

I have an expect script that spawns a process, then does some initialization (authentication), then performs some task that needs prior authentication.

Considering to extend the script to execute multiple tasks after initialization, I wondered whether I could use separate expect processes to perform each task (once the spawned process terminates it needs to re-authenticate).

So that would mean:

1. First expect s*pawns a process and does initialization*.  Then expect exists, but *leaves the spawned process active*.
2. For each task to perform: Start another expect process that *re-attaches* to the process spawned earlier.  This step would repeat as often as needed.
3. A final expect re-attaches to the spawned process and does a *clean shutdown* of that process.

Is that possible?
The advantage would be that for many tasks, a script could be created on the fly, being executed, and then replaced by the next task's script.
Otherwise I would have a very lengthy script...

Comment: Not unless you spawn your command wrapped in [tag:tmux] or [tag:screen]

Comment: Be aware that expect's `interact` command can listen for patterns and automatically do stuff, that may help.

Comment: On tmux and screen: Could you give an example, maybe using `ssh` to log in to some host "interactively", the send more commands to the ssh connection? I'm not quite sue how a solution might look like.

Comment: You'll be better served doing some research, of ask a separate question.

Comment: Just one note: `https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen` refers to `display` issues, which most likely not what you had in mind.

Comment: Trying a solution using `screen` I have the additional problem that after detach/re-attach the screen is redrawn, re-feeding old output back into `expect`.